# Soldering Caps Across Motor Terminals

Tags: soldering

I'm trying to solder 0.1uF capacitors across DC motor terminals to suppress motor noise, as seen [here](https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J15/9) and [here](https://www.dimensionengineering.com/appnotes/simple_robot/), but it's impossible to solder to the motor case. Motor case never holds the solder. Every time I solder the cap to the case, it always breaks off.

Is there anything that I have to do before soldering? I'm using Sn60/Pb40 solder.

[image: Soldering caps across DC motor terminals]

Comment: Do you think that there is a difference vs. soldering caps between two terminals? You do need high power solder to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cases are generally made of steel, and steel is difficult to solder to.

Sand a spot on the case with fine sand paper, and use a larger soldering iron (a little 30W iron won't give enough heat.)
A soldering gun (like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00002N7S0)) will probably do a better job than a normal pencil iron.

When I've had to do something like that, it has usually taken several attempts to get a good joint.

Sand, solder, let cool, pull on wire.  If it comes off, do the whole thing again.

---

There is acid core solder available.  That would work better for soldering to the motor, but you must be sure to remove ALL of the flux afterwards.

I've not tried it, but if you have many of these to do, then you may try this:

1. Sand a spot on the motor with fine sand paper.
2. User a soldering gun and acid core solder to tin the sanded spot on the motor.
3. Clean all traces of the acid flux from the motor.
4. Using a second iron (that has not been in contact with the acid flux) solder the capacitor to the tinned spot on the motor.

Comment: If you can get phosphoric acid it could work .you only need the tiniest amount.

Comment: It makes sense to sand the case. I will try that. I hope sanding works. Thanks.